# Connect textboxes in PDF automatically

Tags: linux, pdf, textbox, ocr, tesseract

I've a document in [Fraktur font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) and performed an OCR with [tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29) (language is *deu-frak*). It took me about 10 days (24h a day) to convert these 23 issues (with each about 400 pages).

The result is a searchable PDF with the original image embedded and the invisible text on top:
[image: Compressed PDF from tesseract]

Now, I've removed the image with [Master PDF Editor](http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php) and turned the text type from "invisible" to "Full text". Now it turned out, that some words weren't recognized by tesseract as such, so each letter is positioned separately:
[image: Text-only PDF from Master PDF Editor]
Notice, that "kommen" was recognized as word but "fruchtbaren" only as a sequence of characters. This makes it impossible to find "fruchtbaren" with the textsearch and when changing the font-size the letters overlap or create ugly gaps.

I'm using Linux and look for a command-line tool which allows to script all 23 PDF documents.

Is it possible to connect textboxes with a minimum distance or even connecting one line would be great?

Thanks.

Comment: *This makes it impossible to find "furchtbaren"* - you are aware that the text says "fruchtbaren", not "furchtbaren"?

Comment: lol... yes, you are right this is a typo - I will correct it. But the question is about textboxes for each letter, which I want to have combined to words.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but I'd go back and experiment with pre-processing, Tesseract parameters, etc on a small representative sample until you get the initial OCR as good as possible (including word segmentation) and then re-run the OCR with your new settings.  If you still find that you need some type of post-processing, I'd, again, build and refine the entire pipeline on a small sample before running your full dataset.

On the surface, it looks like something Tesseract could do a better job at, provided you're giving it clean images with enough scan resolution.

Comment: I already tried to pre-process the images with [textcleaner](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/) (filter, offset and blur) and convert ([black-thresold](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#black-threshold), white-threshold and blur). I used an representative sample, pre-processed it, run tesseract on it and compared the text-output letter by letter. Since I used only text, I had no focus on the word-detection. But I guess a better letter-detection results in a better word-detection...